# Как сделать поле в HTML которое можно будет изменять

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как сделать поле в HTML изменяемым. 
Вот здесь я ввожу данные у форму.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно чтобы при выводе возможно было изменять их

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие для этого нужны технологии? Вот пример этой программы
https://github.com/indreklasn/laravel-5.4-crud-example

Comment: причем тут java?

Comment: а на выводе сейчас `_GET[firstname]` и `_GET[lastname]`, или с БД тянется?

Comment: @user-2147482225, планирую с БД брать.

Answer (score 1):

Выводите не просто Name: $name

```
<input type="text" value="<?=$name?>" name="name"/>
```

Так поле будет изменяемым. Но вообще вопрос очень некорректно задан.